# NavigationDrawer propagates MotionEvent

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, motionevent

I am experiencing the following issue:

In an Android application, I use `NavigationDrawer` for, well ..., navigation.

My issue is that even if the user is opening the `drawer` (by swiping on left screen border) the `ACTION_DOWN` `MotionEvent` is not consumed by the `drawer`, it is propagated to the underlying `view` (a `GLSurfaceView`). In such case, my view receives the `MotionEvent` with the `ACTION_DOWN` action, but never receives the `ACTION_UP` `MotionEvent`. This corrupts my event management logic.

What I would expect is that whenever you receive the `ACTION_DOWN` event (and handle it) you should receive the `ACTION_UP` event when the user stop interacting.

What am I missing ?

Comment: did you reveive ACTION_CANCEL?

Comment: That's what I figured out meanwhile... Post as an answer I'll accept it ! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your GLSurfaceView will most likely receive ACTION_CANCEL event